# php array replicate format in while loop

Tags: php

I want to output the result of a query so that the format is the same as:

```
$links = array(
'Link 1' => '/link1',
'Link 2' => '/link2'
);
```

So the query is

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM link";
$result = mysql_query($query, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)
```

The field that need to be output are:

```
$row['link_title'] and $row['url']
```

Comment: Nope, still unable to understand.

Comment: We do not write code for you, what have you tried? P.S. `mysql_` is deprecated, you should use `PDO` or `Mysqli`

Comment: 'Link 1' would be $row['link_title'] and '/link' would be $row['url'], I'm just unsure as to how to outputthose fields to replicate the format in the first example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a bit more complex then desired or necessary but would this work for you:

```
$a = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    foreach ($row as $k => $v) {
        // Assumes table column name is 'link_title' for the link title
        if ($k == 'link_title') {$title[$a] = $v;} 
        // Assumes table column name is 'url' for the URL
        if ($k == 'url') {$url[$a] = $v;}
    }
    $a++;
}
$i = 0;
foreach ($title as $t) {
    $links[$t] = $url[$i];
    $i++;
}
print_r($links);
```

As @Class stated, if the `link_title`'s **never** repeat than you could do something like this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $array[$row['link_title']] = $row['url'];
}
```

---

Since the `link_title`'s were unique both processes output:

```
Array ( 
    [Moxiecode] => moxiecode.com 
    [Freshmeat] => freshmeat.com 
)
```

Database table + contents:

```
id | link_title |     url       |
---+------------+---------------|
1  | Moxiecode  | moxiecode.com |
---+------------+---------------|
2  | Freshmeat  | freshmeat.com |
```

Comment: shouldn't the first $i++; be $a++;?

Comment: I believe my answer is quite simple and what he needs. I don't see why you need all that code, but it looks like it would do the job as well.

Comment: Your code, inside of a `while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))` would not work, it would overwrite each time it passed. If you pumped the title and url into arrays and then tried your code it would work. At that point you have reduced the lines by maybe 2. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Looking at it again, my code will not work either. I am assuming incorrectly and am going to change accordingly.

Comment: as long as `$row['link_title']` isn't duplicated (whats in it) it should create a new array element with the key as whatever it in `$row['link_title']`

Comment: Thanks for all your help...don't have a working solution yet, but the code I am try to work with can be seen at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LE9yrGAIaIk  Only I need to put the contents of his array from a query

Comment: I tested and fixed my code, it should be working now. I had a typo.

Comment: Great!  Thanks for your help!  The title isn't unique and your code works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
$links = array();
while(foo){
    $links[$row['link_title']] = $row['url'];
}
```

OR you can use which might cause overriding if the title is the same like in the example above

```
$link = array();
$title = array()
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    array_push($title, $row['link_title']);
    array_push($link, $row['url']);
}

$links = array_combine($title, $link);
```

Also use PDO or mysqli functions mysql is deprecated. Here's a tutorial for [PDO](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)

**EDIT:** Example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/uKIMgp I don't know how to create a example with a db but its close enough.

Comment: No that doesn't output in the correct format.  I need to output like var tinyMCELinkList = new Array(
        // Name, URL
        ["Moxiecode", "http://www.moxiecode.com"],
        ["Freshmeat", "http://www.freshmeat.com"],
        ["Sourceforge", "http://www.sourceforge.com"]
);

Comment: @user1911619 I've added a example to simulate a db with a dumping the variable to see whats in it.

Answer (score 0):

You want to echo out the structure of the array?

```
foreach ($Array AS $Values => $Keys)
{
 echo "Array Key: <b>". $Keys ."</b>  Array Value:<b>". $Values ."</b>";
}
```

This will echo out the structure of your exampled array